# mysql query updating but deletes the record in Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I want to update a record with Python in db. But command was deleted record.

```
sql_select_Query = """SELECT id from fuel where imei = '%i' and 
date_format(start_time, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') = date_format(now(), '%%Y-%%m-%%d') and 
isnull(finish_time)""" % (int(lokasyon[2]))

cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
records = cursor.fetchone()

cur.execute("UPDATE fuel set finish_time= '%s', 
kapanis_enlem= '%f', kapanis_boylam= '%f' where id = '%i' " % (date_fin, 
float(liste[3][1:]),float(liste[4][2:]),int(records[0])))

con.commit()
print(cur.rowcount, "record(s) affected")             
       except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
            sys.exit(1)
```

Result:

```
 1 record(s) affected.
```

But the record was deleted.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why did you say it was deleted? have you run "select * from fuel" to seee the change? it should have the updated entry but the finish_time, kapanis_enlem and kapanis_boylam updated.

Comment: Apart from anything else, you should never ever use string interpolation to build up queries. But that is not the source of your problem, whatever your problem actually is.

Comment: I tried it(select * from fuel) but it still deleting record. @MEdwin

Comment: Selects and updates do not delete rows.

Comment: please can you explain why you say it is deleted?